# Dynamically updating the jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query statement

Tags: spring-integration

We are using a `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` with a `poller` to select from a table. The requirement is to select rows with a timestamp within a specific range. That range must be updated each time the database is polled (so rows are not read twice). Originally I envisioned having a separate table to store a datetime, and use the adapter's `update` attribute to update this table. This value would then have been used in the SELECT statement defined in the `query` attribute, as part of the WHERE clause against the main table.

We have now been told that while we will have read access to the main table, we will not be given permission to add anything to the existing schema, or have write permissions. This rules out using a separate table in which to continually update the timestamp used by the main SQL query.

The option of defining in the `query` attribute some SpEL which would return a dynamically generated SELECT statement will also not work. This is because the SpEL will only be evaluated once when Spring loads.

Is there another way to dynamically update the SQL in the `query` attribute?

Otherwise, what is the correct strategy for this use case, where the SQL which is used by the adapter must change each time the database is polled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter source to the adapter and use queries like:

```
"SELECT * from FOO where KEY=:key"
```

See attribute `select-sql-parameter-source`.

You can write your own parameter source, but also see `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory`.

Comment: Also see ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory.